# user account about to expire and list his groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i am having a problem to get ad group for specific user who is about to expire in less than 8 days.

i am able to find users with:

`$users = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan "7" | FT sAMAccountName -HideTableHeaders`

but when i try foreach:

`foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUser -identity $user -Properties memberof | select -ExpandProperty memberof | %{ $_.Split(',')[0]; 
}`

i get:

Get-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData" 
value of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData" to type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser".
At C:\scripts\get expiry.ps1:13 char:23
+     Get-ADUser -identity $user -Properties memberof | select -ExpandProperty member ...
+                          ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

but for one user it works:

`Get-ADUser -identity guest1 -Properties memberof | select -ExpandProperty memberof | %{ $_.Split(',')[0]; }`

CN=MY_GROUP

my question is how to convert FormatEndData into ADUser?
or is there any better way how to get what i need?

ANSWER:

with small help i was able to get what i want with this code below

`$datefrom = (Get-Date)
$dateto = (Get-Date).AddDays(8) 
$users = Get-ADUser -filter {(AccountExpirationDate -gt $datefrom) -and (AccountExpirationDate -lt $dateto)} -Properties samaccountname,memberof`

`foreach ($user in $users) 
{ 
$groups = $user | select -Property samaaccountname -ExpandProperty memberof | %{ $_.Split(',')[0]; } | %{ $_.Split('=')[1]; }
foreach ($group in $groups){
    if ($group -eq "MY_GROUP")
    {
    Write-Host $user.samaccountname
    echo $group
    }

 }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what it is you're actually putting into $users.  Format-Table takes objects from the pipeline and adds screen formatting to make a nice table for you.  When you send it to a variable, that's what's in the varialble - a bunch of strings and format control characters - not your powershell objects.

Get rid of the format-table and see if it doesn't work better.